# C# script in .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hopefully someone can help with this :)

We have this code which I think is causing an issue

```
if (gvAccess.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text == "0")
{
    gvAccess.Visible=false;
}
else
{
    Button1.Visible=false;
    RhombusL.Visible=false;
    Permission.Visible=false;
    EmailL.Visible=false;
    Email.Visible=false;
    SiteL.Visible=false;
    Site.Visible=false;
    RhombusPerErr.Visible=false;
    Enter.Text="This user already has access at your centre.";
    gvAccess.Visible=false;
}
```

Basically our SQL query will count a number of rows, and returns the count - just 1 row and 1 column. When I set gvAccess.Visible=true, I can see the returned count (and is correct), but it isn't comparing to "0".

Is there anything obvious here? Any help appreciated :)

Aaron

Comment: What does the debugger tell you about the value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
if (gvAccess.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].toString() == "0")
{
    gvAccess.Visible=false;
}
else
{
    Button1.Visible=false;
    RhombusL.Visible=false;
    Permission.Visible=false;
    EmailL.Visible=false;
    Email.Visible=false;
    SiteL.Visible=false;
    Site.Visible=false;
    RhombusPerErr.Visible=false;
    Enter.Text="This user already has access at your centre.";
    gvAccess.Visible=false;
}
```

You might want to put a break point on the code and see if you are looking for the right value in the table as well, so you can look at the entire resulting datatable.